# Background Colour to DIV Element

Tags: html, css

I have this screen currently:

[image]

I want to add a background-colour of blue to the `div class="information"` (the entire `div` element on the right), the same way how there is a background-colour of brown to the `div class="login"` (the `div` on the left). However, when I try to use the same approach as I did for the right `div` as I did for the left `div`, it isn't working. How can I achieve the expected?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lora&display=swap');
body {
  background-color: #DBE2EF;
  font-family: Lora;
}

.login {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #A4907C;
  width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 130px;
  margin-left: 180px;
}

.logintxt {
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.loginemailtxt {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 250px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: Lora;
}

.loginemailtxt::placeholder {
  color: black;
  padding-left: 3px;
}

.loginemailtxt:focus {
  border: 1px solid #3F72AF;
}

.loginpwdtxt {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 250px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: Lora;
}

.loginpwdtxt::placeholder {
  color: black;
  padding-left: 3px;
}

.loginpwdtxt:focus {
  border: 1px solid #3F72AF;
}

.loginbtn {
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-left: -190px;
  background-color: #3F72AF;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Lora;
}

.loginbtn:hover {
  background-color: #068FFF;
}

#loginNoEmail {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #F24C3D;
  margin-left: 140px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  width: 215px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#loginNoPassword {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #F24C3D;
  margin-left: 145px;
  margin-top: 105px;
  width: 205px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#loginIncorrectCreds {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #F24C3D;
  margin-left: 145px;
  margin-top: 105px;
  width: 205px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.infoHead1 {
  margin-top: -500px;
  margin-left: 915px;
}

.infoHead2 {
  margin-left: 815px;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 340px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/js/all.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="login">
    <h2 class="textHead">MedConnect</h2>
    <h2 class="logintxt">Log In to Your Account</h2>
    <input type="text" class="loginemailtxt" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
    <h5 id="loginNoEmail">Please enter your email address.</h5>
    <h5 id="loginNoPassword">Please enter your password.</h5>
    <h5 id="loginIncorrectCreds">Incorrect Email or Password</h5>
    <input type="password" class="loginpwdtxt" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <button class="loginbtn" type="button" name="button">Log In</button>
    <h5 style="margin-top: 160px; font-family: Lora;">Don't have an Account? <u style="cursor: pointer;">Sign Up</u></h5>
    <h6 style="margin-top: 40px; font-family: Lora;">By clicking "Log In", you log back into your Existing Account</h6>
  </div>

  <div class="information">
    <h2 class="infoHead1">All-In-One</h2>
    <h2 class="infoHead2">Medical Consultancy Platform</h2>
    <div class="infoIcons1">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-person" style="font-size: 40px; margin-left: 815px; margin-top: 50px;"></i>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-calendar-check" style="font-size: 40px; margin-left: 130px;"></i>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-handshake-angle" style="font-size: 40px; margin-left: 130px;"></i>
      <h6 style="margin-left: 230px; text-align: center;">Connect with <br>Consultants</h6>
      <h6 style="margin-left: 555px; text-align: center; margin-top: -52px;">Book Online Interactions <br>Anytime</h6>
      <h6 style="margin-left: 890px; margin-top: -52px; text-align: center;">Volunteer as a <br>Verified Consultant</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="infoIcons2" style="margin-top: -20px;">
      <i class="fa-brands fa-youtube" style="font-size: 40px; margin-left: 805px; margin-top: 50px;"></i>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-file" style="font-size: 40px; margin-left: 125px;"></i>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass" style="font-size: 40px; margin-left: 125px;"></i>
      <h6 style="margin-left: 230px; text-align: center;">Self-Educate with <br>Resources</h6>
      <h6 style="margin-left: 555px; text-align: center; margin-top: -52px;">Get Personalised, Detailed <br>Prescriptions</h6>
      <h6 style="margin-left: 890px; margin-top: -52px; text-align: center;">Search for specific <br>Medical Help</h6>
    </div>
    <h5 style="margin-left: 860px; margin-top: 40px;">Non Profit • Start for Free • Cancel Anytime</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any CSS selectors that target .information

Comment: The way you are positioning your columns is very incorrect (with the negative and very high margins) - content positioning simply doesn't "work that way". You need to fix that fundamentally, rather than solving THIS question. In other words.... the problem you are experiencing now...you are making for yourself in the first place.

Comment: What specific CSS rule are you referring to in the code shown which isn't doing what you expect?

Comment: @mayersdesign Alright, so how else should I do it?

Comment: Flexbox is the latest way, as suggested below. A framework like Bootstrap would make that much easier for you I imagine.

Comment: Understood. So is using flexbox going to impact the website any differently than the approach that I'm using right now (negative and high margins)?

Comment: It is going to make it display correctly on mobile for one thing (which you current approach does not) - and that's very, very important.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for your help. However, is there anything I can do currently to add the background-colour to that second `div`? Because I'm not really looking to use flexbox for this page (maybe the next pages).

Comment: @SreejaJacobs: *"is there anything I can do currently to add the background-colour to that second div?"* - Yes, by targeting the `<div>` with a CSS rule which specifies a `background-color` value.  Exactly as you do for the `.login` element.  Though I suspect you'll find that the `.information` element isn't **where** you want it to be, precisely **because** the layout is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your layout is a... mess!
I would suggest you to learn a little about css grid, check here :
https://www.quackit.com/css/grid/tutorial/css_grid_introduction.cfm

I made a snippet with grid, and simplify a lot your layout. Functional, but could still be more simplify

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #DBE2EF;
  font-family: Lora, sans-serif;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 2em;
  max-width: 80%;
  max-height: 80%;
}

.container h2 {
  margin: 1em 0;
}

.login {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(8, auto);
  padding: 1em 3em;
  background-color: #A4907C;
}

.login>* {
  text-align: center;
}

.login input {
  font-size: 1.25em;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
}

.loginemailtxt {
  border: 1px solid black;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 1em 0 2em 0;
}

.loginemailtxt::placeholder {
  color: black;
  padding-left: 3px;
}

.loginemailtxt:focus {
  border: 1px solid #3F72AF;
}

.loginpwdtxt {
  border: 1px solid black;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.loginpwdtxt::placeholder {
  color: black;
  padding-left: 3px;
}

.loginpwdtxt:focus {
  border: 1px solid #3F72AF;
}

.loginbtn {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #3F72AF;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.loginbtn:hover {
  background-color: #068FFF;
}

#errorMsg {
  opacity: 0;
}

#loginNoEmail {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #F24C3D;
  border-radius: 5px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#loginNoPassword {
  background-color: #F24C3D;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: none;
}

#loginIncorrectCreds {
  background-color: #F24C3D;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: none;
}

.information {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, auto);
  padding: 1em 3em;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
}

.information h6 {
  margin: 0;
}

.infoHead2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding-left: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.infoIcons {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
}

.infoIcons svg {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="login">
    <h2 class="textHead">MedConnect</h2>
    <h2 class="logintxt">Log In to Your Account</h2>
    <input type="text" class="loginemailtxt" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
    <input type="password" class="loginpwdtxt" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <h5>Don't have an Account? <u style="cursor: pointer;">Sign Up</u></h5>
    <h6>By clicking "Log In", you log back into your Existing Account</h6>
    <button class="loginbtn" type="button" name="button">Log In</button>
    <div id="errorMsg">
      <h5 id="loginNoEmail">Please enter your email address.</h5>
      <h5 id="loginNoPassword">Please enter your password.</h5>
      <h5 id="loginIncorrectCreds">Incorrect Email or Password</h5>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="information">
    <h2 class="infoHead1">All-In-One</h2>
    <h2 class="infoHead2">Medical Consultancy Platform</h2>
    <div class="infoIcons">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-person"></i>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-calendar-check"></i>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-handshake-angle"></i>
      <h6 style="text-align: center;">Connect with <br>Consultants</h6>
      <h6 style="text-align: center;;">Book Online Interactions <br>Anytime</h6>
      <h6 style="text-align: center;">Volunteer as a <br>Verified Consultant</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="infoIcons">
      <i class="fa-brands fa-youtube"></i>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-file"></i>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
      <h6 style="text-align: center;">Self-Educate with <br>Resources</h6>
      <h6 style="text-align: center;">Get Personalised, Detailed <br>Prescriptions</h6>
      <h6 style="text-align: center;">Search for specific <br>Medical Help</h6>
    </div>
    <h5>Non Profit • Start for Free • Cancel Anytime</h5>
  </div>
</div>

<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/js/all.js"></script>
```

Comment: I made a few changes. It looks good now. However, the "Medical Consultancy Platform" text in yellow isn't moving left, right, up or down at all, no matter what I try. I want to move it a little bit up as shown in the image in the question. Right now, it is too down.

Comment: theres is a class .container h2 {margin:1em 0} at beginning. That gives to all h2 in container a top and bottom margin of 1 em. Put margin:0, check the result. you will have to add margin after, but perhaps more flexible.

Comment: I tried it. Still doesn't work. I'm trying to move the "Medical Consultancy Platform" closer to the "All-In-One" text as shown in the image. This doesn't do it though. Even after adding margin after.

Answer (score 1):

Your layout is misconfigured, you shouldn't place all items with position: fixed. Your design is broken when the window size changes. Use relative positioning and also i suggest you to learn flexbox.

When you succeed creating a well layout you won't need to specify height and width for container it should auto-scale with its content.

I will provide a code snippet with a well designed flexbox you may try similar things:

```css
/*
* BEGIN
* UTILITY CLASSES
* (YOU MAY USE PRIMEFLEX, TAILWIND OR BOOTSTRAP FOR UTILITY CLASSES)
* /BEGIN
*/

.flex-col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-wrap {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.center-content {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.gap-2 {
  gap: 2rem;
}

.h-full {
  height: 100%;
}

/*
* END
* UTILITY CLASSES
* /END
* 
*/

.box {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.bg-brown {
  background-color: burlywood;
}

.bg-blue {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

.bg-red {
  background-color: red;
}

.icon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MedConnect | Log In or Sign Up</title>
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/js/all.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="flex-row gap-2 center-content">
    <div class="box bg-brown">
      <div class="flex-col center-content gap-2 h-full">
        <div class="flex-row center-content">
          <div class="icon">icon1</div>
          <div class="icon">icon2</div>
          <div class="icon">icon3</div>
          <div class="icon">icon4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-row center-content">
          <div class="icon">icon1</div>
          <div class="icon">icon2</div>
          <div class="icon">icon3</div>
          <div class="icon">icon4</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box bg-blue">
      <div class="flex-col bg-red">
        <div>This red container scales with its content</div>
        <div>row 2</div>
        <div>row 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you make this according to my code, because the code in the answer isn't relative to my code.